# Compute input from JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextpane, jcomponent

I don't seem to find any good source of how to work with inputs from JTextPane. What I basically want to achieve is the following: I have 3 JTextPanes, 3 buttons aligned with them. When I would press button 'a' I would want to read data from TextPane 'b' and TextPane 'c'. I've created a class for that action so that I will only need to call the class's constructor and will do the job for me. I know this is a low-class question, but please consider I've just started to examine Swing. 
So, this is the class I created for reading input from TextPanes:

```
public class InputReader extends AbstractAction{

private JTextPane componentToReadA;
private JTextPane componentToReadB;

public InputReader(JTextPane a, JTextPane b) {
    componentToReadA = a;
    componentToReadB = b;

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    componentToReadA.getText();
    componentToReadB.getText();
}
```

Now, I know getText reads data in as String, but I thought I could transform it to double via `parseDouble();`

[image]

Comment: What is your question? How to convert String to double?

Comment: No, my question is how to make the program work with the values put in to the textpanes.

Comment: Have no idea, how should work you program. Please provide a [mcve], which demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Ok. So the idea is to compute Pythagoras on a GUI. You have 3 buttons on the screen, 3 textpanes below them. Once you press either of the buttons-which themselves represent a side of the triangle- you can input numbers into the textpanes except the one you want to compute, then the program executes the computation and gives you the result on a pop-up. I have 1 class that sets buttons disabled and the one that is highlighted above would be the one that reads the data inserted into the textpanes. I upload a picture as well to my original comment.

Comment: 1) You should use `JFormattedTextField` instead of `JTextPane`. 2) I still don't understand what is your problem. 3) Your [mcve] is is still missing.

Comment: What is the error? What is currently happening that is not what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
componentToReadA.getText();
```

You don't do anything with the text in your ActionListener. You need to assign the text to a variable if you want to use the text.

You need something like:

```
int valueA = Integer.parseInt( componentToReadA.getText().trim() );
System.out.println( valueA );
```

So know you have an integer value to do your Pythagoras calculations with.